# Как можно написать короче и лаконичнее? Метод объекта

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток
Функционал метода следующий:

- Пушится в массив значение `input.value`
- Если `input.value.lenght >=` , тогда режется с 1-го индекса до 21 и добавляется в список 21 символ + троеточие.
- Если меньше, то просто пушится `input.value`
- Мне кажется, что это можно совершенно короче записать и не повторять одинаковый код... 
   В стадии обучения, поэтому буду рад совету :)

```
        btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (input.value.length <= 21) {                                      // если длинна меньше или равна 21 символу
                movieList.innerHTML = '';
                movieDB.movies.push(input.value);
                movieDB.movies.sort().forEach((film, i) => {
                    movieList.innerHTML += `
                    <li class="promo__interactive-item">${i + 1}. ${film}
                        <div class="delete"></div>
                    </li>
                    `;
                })
            } else {  
                movieList.innerHTML = '';                                        // если длинна более 21 символа
                movieDB.movies.push(input.value);
                movieDB.movies.sort().forEach((film, i) => {                                                
                    movieList.innerHTML += `
                    <li class="promo__interactive-item">${i + 1}. ${film.slice(0 , 21)}...
                        <div class="delete"></div>
                    </li>
                    `;
                    console.log('Больше 21-го символа!');
                });
            };
        }
    )}
```

Comment: Первое что бросилось в глаза:
1. Вынесите всё начиная со строки "if...." в отдельную функцию и в слушатели запускайте её.
2. Комменты кода над строкой которой они касаются (у Вас справа)
3. Не используйте кириллицу в коде - pichite hotiaby tak. Мы не говорим о консоль.лог и подобном.

Comment: 4. Если учитесь, главное что код Вам понятен. Через полгода вернётесь и переделаете, это неизбежно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это, конечно, не ваш код, т.к. воспроизвести каждую переменную это долго :) Но суть в том чтобы просто с самого начала сохранить в отдельной переменной значение `value.length >= 21`. Ниже я привёл пример который это наглядно показывает как надо было сделать, если уловите суть то легко сможете переделать свою функцию:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');
const maxLength = 21;

input.oninput = (e) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const isBigText = value.length >= maxLength;
  
  output.innerHTML = value.slice(0, maxLength) + `${isBigText ? '...' : ''}`;
}
```

```html
<label for="input">Input text</label>
<input type="text" id="input">
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Блин, это же гениально :)
Дааа, я уловил суть и понял насколько пока что я мало вижу в решении подобных задач :)
Спасибо большое!)

Comment: @Alexeevich Обращайтесь! Подтвердите мой ответ, если вам не трудно, буду очень признателен!